# SQL sentence in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, sql, node.js, vue.js

Can I execute sql sentences in javacript without calling an external php file?

I have seen that I can use SQL with node.js easily but, I'm useing Vue.js and it's my first time so i'm a little bit confused.

In summary, I want to connect to a database without useing php and I don't know if it would work.

Thanks you!

Comment: Where is that SQL database located?

Comment: Client side js can't connect to a sql server on it's own. If you could, it would be a serious security issue as well, since everyone could check the source and get the credentials and make what ever calls to the database they want.

Comment: If it's on a server, you simply can't using just front end tools. Voted to close, since this is not a specific problem but rather looking for a tutorial.

Comment: You cant !! not with frontend library whether its vue,angular or vanilla js .you just cant. You be needing any middlelayer like php or node.js for creating database connection.

Comment: Ok thanks, it was just a crazy idea.

Comment: You might want to read up on [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming). Node and PHP are server side while vue is a client side library. Everything that's client side is downloaded to the users client and can be read and manipulated by the users.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to develop only javascript, it is possible to use [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/) server (alternative apache, nginx etc.)

For communication with db we can recommend [framework Express](https://expressjs.com/) and easy [connect any sql](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/database-integration.html#sql-server)